# Correct way to use a th:with Thymeleaf local variable within a form

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I use form backing objects that all share an abstract base class. One of the properties of this base class is named `model` but it can represent anything of the entities of my domain model.

Now what I would like to do is use `th:with` in order to rename the `model` property to the name of my entities i.e. `curriculum`, `advertisement`, etc. thus my different Thymeleaf templates would read nicer with `advertisement` than with `model`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<form th:object="${advertisementForm}" th:with="advertisement=*{model}" th:action="@{${postUrl}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

(`model` is a property of `advertisementForm`)

When I then try to access my newly created `advertisement` variable as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="${advertisement.id}"/>
```

I get a:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'advertisement' available as request attribute
```

indicating that the local variable is not used.

Answer (score 0):

the use of th:with is fine but for th:field is incorrect

possible ways for th:field to be used

```
th:field="*{model.id}" -- here * can be read as a direct replacement of the form object defined    with th:object

th:field="${advertisementForm.model.id}" --- if you are $ you need to define the complete path
```

possible solution 
Instead of using th:field use html id & name. Set value using th:value

```
<input class="form-control"
           type="text"
           th:value="${client.name}" id="clientName" name="clientName" />
```

But I would not strongly suggest not do because as mentioned here 
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs